# How to set up password on xmrpool.net mining pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, privacy, security, how-to

I'm new to mining and I don't know how to set up a password and a username on [xmrpool.net](https://xmrpool.net/) mining pool.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Username - your wallet id

Password - *workerId*:*your@email*

You should specify above as parameters or configuration of your miner. If you have done everything correctly, your online account will be created automatically. To login there, use wallet is as username and *your@email* as a password.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: what is workerID again?

Answer (score 0):

{
    "api": {
        "id": null,
        "worker-id": null
    },
    "http": {
        "enabled": false,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 0,
        "access-token": null,
        "restricted": true
    },
    "autosave": true,
    "background": false,
    "colors": true,
    "randomx": {
        "init": -1,
        "mode": "auto",
        "numa": true
    },
    "cpu": {
        "enabled": true,
        "huge-pages": true,
        "hw-aes": null,
        "priority": 2,
        "memory-pool": false,
        "yield": true,
        "asm": true,
        "argon2-impl": null,
        "argon2": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "cn": [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 2]
        ],
        "cn-heavy": [
            [1, 0]
        ],
        "cn-lite": [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 3]
        ],
        "cn-pico": [
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3]
        ],
        "cn/gpu": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "rx": [0, 2],
        "rx/wow": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "cn/0": false,
        "cn-lite/0": false,
        "rx/arq": "rx/wow"
    },
    "opencl": {
        "enabled": false,
        "cache": true,
        "loader": null,
        "platform": "AMD",
        "cn/0": false,
        "cn-lite/0": false
    },
    "cuda": {
        "enabled": false,
        "loader": null,
        "nvml": true,
        "cn/0": false,
        "cn-lite/0": false
    },
    "donate-level": 1,
    "donate-over-proxy": 1,
    "log-file": null,
    "pools": [
        {
            "algo": null,
            "coin": null,
            "url": "pool",
            "user": "wallet",
            "pass": "x",
            "rig-id": null,
            "nicehash": false,
            "keepalive": false,
            "enabled": true,
            "tls": false,
            "tls-fingerprint": null,
            "daemon": false,
            "self-select": null
        }
    ],
    "print-time": 60,
    "health-print-time": 60,
    "retries": 5,
    "retry-pause": 5,
    "syslog": false,
    "user-agent": null,
    "watch": true
}

on this json file how can I set passwo